# SQL JOIN shows duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query

```
SELECT  DCEB_Aspirantes.folio, 
Nombre,apaterno,amaterno,programa ,
DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte1.usuario, eval1,eval2,eval3, eval4 , eval5, 
eval6 , eval7, 
res1,res2,res3, res4 , res5,res6 ,res7

 FROM DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte1 
RIGHT JOIN DCEB_Aspirantes ON DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte1.id_aspirante = 
DCEB_Aspirantes.id_aspirante  

JOIN
DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte2 ON 
DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte2.id_aspirante = DCEB_Aspirantes.id_aspirante
```

In the DCEB_Aspirantes table i have the Nombre,apaterno,amaterno,programa

```
DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte1 has eval1, eal2 , eval3 -- eval7
DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte2 has res1, res2 ,res3 -- res7
```

I have only one register in DCEB_Aspirantes (a user), ad this user has and evaluation in the other 2 columns. i wanted a result like this

```
User -  Teacher -   eval1 - eval2 -  eval3 -eval4-  res1 -res2  res3 -res4 -res7
```

The problem is the user has an evaluation from 3 teachers, so there will be 3 rows, i have that result but instead of 3 rows it shows 9 rows (3 times the same row)?

This is the result
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+

| Folio | Nombre | usuario | eval1 | eval2 | eval7 | res1 | res2 | res7 |

+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+

|     66 | Erick  | usu1    |    10 |     9 |     4 |    8 |    8 |    8 |

|     66 | Erick  | usu1    |    10 |     9 |     4 |    9 |    9 |    9 |

|     66 | Erick  | usu1    |    10 |     9 |     4 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|     66 | Erick  | usu2    |     6 |     6 |     6 |    8 |    8 |    8 |

|     66 | Erick  | usu2    |     6 |     6 |     6 |    9 |    9 |    9 |

|     66 | Erick  | usu2    |     6 |     6 |     6 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|     66 | Erick  | usu3    |    10 |    10 |    10 |    8 |    8 |    8 |

|     66 | Erick  | usu3    |    10 |    10 |    10 |    9 |    9 |    9 |

|     66 | Erick  | usu3    |    10 |    10 |    10 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+

Comment: On a side-note please start using `aliases` as it helps with readability and a couple other things.

Comment: you mean 3 rows are exact replica of each other? no difference at all?

Comment: Try using a `LEFT JOIN` instead - I think that would fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve the issue, but try this, I have not seen your database so not sure of the solution.

```
SELECT  A.folio, 
Nombre,apaterno,amaterno,programa ,
P1.usuario, eval1,eval2,eval3, eval4 , eval5, 
eval6 , eval7, 
res1,res2,res3, res4 , res5,res6 ,res7

FROM DCEB_Aspirantes A
LEFT JOIN DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte1 P1  ON A.id_aspirante = 
P1.id_aspirante  
LEFT JOIN  DCEB_Aspirante_has_Eval_Parte2 P2 ON A.id_aspirante = 
P2.id_aspirante
```

Comment: Hi!. i tried your solution but still it does a 3x3 result. mixing every evaluation, i tried to edit the question with a result table

Comment: So the results are not replicating, the result is different

Comment: you need to decide on what you want in the last three columns, if you want sum? max? min? or what exactly. Use group by and use sum/max/min for the last three columns,

Comment: whatever you are getting the result, is what you will get if you want the last three columns